# (Python) Help speeding up apply lambda row

Tags: python, apply

I've got some code that works, but needs speeding up

I've got a dataframe of 100 million rows. Within it, there's one column I care about, containing floats. I also have a second dataframe of 10,000 rows, containing two columns of floats.

```
>>> df_1
           col_A
0          12.9900
1          5.0001
...        ...
100000000  6.0070


>>> df_2
           col_B      col_C
0          5.0000      0.19
1          6.0080      0.43
...        ...         ...
9999       13.0000     10.95
```

My goal is, for every value in col_A, search for the closest value in col_B, and then return the corresponding value of col_C in a new column of df_1. So for example, take 12.99 in df_1; the closest value in col_B is 13, so it returns 10.95 in the new column. This is what I have written:

```
def find_nearest1(row,array):
    idx,val = min(enumerate(array['colB']), key=lambda x: abs(x[1]-row['colA']))
    return array['ColC'][idx]

df_1['new_col']=df_1.apply(lambda row: find_nearest1(row,df_2),axis=1)

# The result is:
>>> df_1
           col_A        new_col
0          12.9900      10.95
1          5.0001       0.19
...        ...          ...
100000000  6.0070       0.43
```

My code works fine for small datasets, but it is painfully slow for my dataset of 100 million rows. Any ideas on how to make this faster?

Comment: `.apply` will always be slow, but fundamentally the problem is your alogrithm, which is just a brute-force search for the nearest neighbor. There are various nearest-neighbor algorithms, likely requiring you to use an auxiliary data-structure, that might help you speed this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted in the comments, you need a better algorithm. One optimization you can make is to sort `col_B`, and that way you can perform binary search to find the closest element. I put both implementations in a `test.py` file with 1000 random elements. Here's some bootstrap code to test for yourself (`find_nearest2` is the improved function, I stored these results in `"other_new_col"`).

### O(N log N) solution that maintains same behavior as original O(N^2) solution:

```
import bisect
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Original                                                                                                                                                                                                  
def find_nearest1(row,array):
    idx,val = min(enumerate(array['col_B']), key=lambda x: abs(x[1]-row['col_A']))
    return array['col_C'][idx]

# Optimized                                                                                                                                                                                                 
def find_nearest2(row,array):
    idx = bisect.bisect_left(array['col_B'].values, row['col_A'])
    arr_len = len(array['col_C'])
    if idx == 0:
        return array['col_C'].iloc[0]
    elif idx == arr_len:
        return array['col_C'].iloc[-1]
    else:
        diff1 = abs(array['col_B'].iloc[idx] - row['col_A'])
        diff2 = abs(array['col_B'].iloc[idx-1] - row['col_A'])
        m = min(diff1, diff2)
        if np.isclose(m, diff1):
            return array['col_C'].iloc[idx]
        else:
            return array['col_C'].iloc[idx-1]

np.random.seed(1) # Set seed for reproducability                                                                                                                                                            

size = 1000
df1_data = np.random.random(size)
df1_cols = ["col_A"]
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(df1_data, columns=df1_cols)

df2_data = {"col_B": np.random.random(size), "col_C": np.random.random(size)}
df_2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df2_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Original                                                                                                                                                                                              
    df_1['new_col']=df_1.apply(lambda row: find_nearest1(row,df_2),axis=1)

    # Optimized                                                                                                                                                                                             
    df_2_sorted = df_2.sort_values('col_B')
    df_1['other_new_col'] = df_1.apply(lambda row: find_nearest2(row, df_2_sorted), axis=1)

    print(df_1)
```

and this outputs (so you can verify original behavior is maintained):

```
        col_A   new_col  other_new_col
0    0.417022  0.842518       0.842518
1    0.720324  0.633461       0.633461
2    0.000114  0.327524       0.327524
3    0.302333  0.947542       0.947542
4    0.146756  0.985317       0.985317
5    0.092339  0.875530       0.875530
6    0.186260  0.348727       0.348727
7    0.345561  0.471819       0.471819
8    0.396767  0.674607       0.674607
9    0.538817  0.696878       0.696878
10   0.419195  0.695152       0.695152
...
990  0.812507  0.584883       0.584883
991  0.283802  0.497448       0.497448
992  0.527847  0.490089       0.490089
993  0.339417  0.905808       0.905808
994  0.554667  0.745292       0.745292
995  0.974403  0.615726       0.615726
996  0.311703  0.594144       0.594144
997  0.668797  0.571321       0.571321
998  0.325967  0.576978       0.576978
999  0.774477  0.963032       0.963032
```

### Some performance results:

```
bash-3.2$ ipython
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 12:04:33)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from test import find_nearest1, find_nearest2, df_1, df_2

In [2]: %timeit df_1['new_col']=df_1.apply(lambda row: find_nearest1(row,df_2),axis=1)
6.04 s ± 13.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [3]: %timeit df_2_sorted = df_2.sort_values('col_B')
201 µs ± 3.25 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [4]: df_2_sorted = df_2.sort_values('col_B')

In [5]: %timeit df_1.apply(lambda row: find_nearest2(row, df_2_sorted), axis=1)
111 ms ± 1.67 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**So, the optimized implementation is about 50x faster.** This is because the original algorithm is O(N^2), but you can do it in O(N log N) time. The factor of speedup will be even better for 100 million rows.

HTH.